# Images can't be displayed

Tags: html, css

I'm using a website template I found on Google.

Everything was going great until I noticed it won't let me display my own images. However, it can display other images that comes together with the template. I want to display a default avatar image for the My Account page, but it can't displayed.

```
<img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
```

Even writting like below won't work either.

```
<img src="images/avatar.png">
```

Here is a screenshot for the image file path:
[image]

Comment: Where have you kept `avatar.png` file? Can you show the file path?

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim It's in the images folder, where all the other images are kept.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your project directory along with files? I want to see this just to check whether the path from your html file to the image file is correct.

Comment: Just shared the screenshot.

Comment: Oh my... I realized I have a duplicate folder of the entire template, and the images was saved at my older folder. My bad. 

Thanks for the help

Comment: so the problem was path related

Comment: Yup. It was the path.

Answer (score 1):

It is Because of 'img' tags need to be self closing, but your tag is not self closing. Try like this:

`<img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"/>`

Comment: I tried it but the image still can't be displayed unfortunately. Maybe I need to use a different image?

Answer (score 0):

Close your image tag , use this :-

```
<img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"/>
```

and if it doesn't work try to find out where you have placed your image.